# OpenWRT XMPP client library?

Tags: python, openwrt

is there any python XMPP client library for OpenWRT?

tnx.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably have to cross-compile [xmpppy](http://xmpppy.sourceforge.net/) yourself using the [OpenWRT SDK](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/obtain.firmware.sdk).